# How to approach Flyway migration when using Envers?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, flyway, hibernate-envers

I need to add some data to my DB. Simple INSERT statement. I would do it in Flyway migration SQL script. But how to approach this task when Hibernate Envers is also in place? Do I need to manually alter audit tables and revision table? Or is there any better approach?

I was thinking about java-based migration using hibernate (it would automatically update also audit tables), but I'm afraid that's not the way. I don't know, how could I do it. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

I am afraid that you do not have other choices than do it manually.
Envers detects Hibernate's Session operations, so if your migrations are outside the Session you have to alter audit tables yourself.

Comment: I have an existing project. Because of no much info found about this use case,  I think I will manually create all the inserts from previous Flyway migrations with REV = 1 so it will be considered as "since first version".